# Bleeding-edge elementary OS ISO or PPA?

Tags: ppa, iso

Is it possible to obtain testing releases of elementary OS ISO images? Otherwise - are there any repos for the latest unstable/testing/etc. packages? How do I add them here?

Answer (score -1):

You can try the daily PPA which contains unstable pre release software. To add it run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily 
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Since this gives you bleeding-edge daily builds, your system is most likely going to be broken if you do this.

Comment: Well of course, because you need to run it on top of the supported version of Ubuntu.